# SEO effect of many articles having a similar title and content structure?

Tags: seo, content, title

I'm building a diet directory on my weight loss site, and the *structure* for those diet descriptions will be similar (the actual content will be unique though).

Here are some examples of the similarities that the diet descriptions will have: *how does the diet work?* will be in every diet description. Also the title for every diet will be something along the lines of *Diet X reviews and information*, with the reviews and information part being the same across all diet descriptions.

Can having many titles that are similar to each other in that way, and also having some `h2` headings that are identical across articles hurt the SEO rankings of those articles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the content I would say that having the same structure will not hurt SEO, as long as the content itself is really unique. It is like recipes, they all have ingredients and a description, but are unique.

I personally would try to have the `h2` headings unique and not identical across the articles or try to put the name of the diet into the `h2` tags like *how does the NAME diet work?*. Having all the same `h2` will not hurt SEO but having them more unique might help your site.